# After Atom update on Debian it is no longer possible to launch the editor

Tags: debian, apt, atom-editor

After the update of Atom to version 1.47.0 in Debian Buster(Gnome Wayland), the editor won't execute anymore. No error appears, and there's no Atom process in `top`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After launching the editor via terminal I saw the error:

> `/usr/bin/atom, linha 190:  3300 Trace/breakpoint trap   nohup
>   "$ATOM_PATH" --executed-from="$(pwd)" --pid=$$ "$@" >
>   "$ATOM_HOME/nohup.out" 2>&1
>   [3300:0520/012550.477548:FATAL:setuid_sandbox_host.cc(157)] The SUID
>   sandbox helper binary was found, but is not configured correctly.
>   Rather than run without sandboxing I'm aborting now. You need to make
>   sure that /usr/share/atom/chrome-sandbox is owned by root and has mode
>   4755.`

So I changed the permission of /usr/share/atom/chrome-sandbox by using

```
chmod 4755 /usr/share/atom/chrome-sandbox
```

And Atom started to work again.

Comment: Note that the `-R` option made you change permissions on the _contents_ of that directory too, which may not have been needed or wanted.

Comment: @Kusalananda It sounds like `/usr/share/atom/chrome-sandbox` might be a single binary file, not a directory. That seems to be true on my system that has a number of other Chrome-based products installed. If that's true in this case also, then the `-R` option did no harm at all, even though it was unnecessary. But in general, since `chmod -R` in a wrong place can cause a great deal of problems, it would be good to be extra careful with it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this fix doesn't appear to be permanent. It allowed me to open `atom` once, then I got the same error again the next time.

Comment: @Carcigenicate It happened after a reboot?

Comment: @telcoM I think you are right. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem when I updated to version 1.47.0. As you mentioned you could modify permissions, but a better fix for the time being would be to just downgrade to the previous version.

This command shows all of the versions you can downgrade to (you should probably pick v1.46.0):

```
sudo apt-cache policy atom
```

After just run:

```
sudo apt install atom=1.46.0
```

Btw this assumes that you have atom repo in you sources.list.d directory. You can check with:

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
ls
```

You should then see atom.list. If you don't, see [installing atom](https://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/installing-atom/)

Comment: Actually I didn't said that you could remove it. I said to change the permissions.

Comment: sorry, another question was posted with a similar problem, and was asking whether disabling sandbox with `--no-sandbox` would be safe... I assumed your question was similar when I saw "sandbox". by bad